# python client request fails with default timeout

Tags: python, python-2.7, elasticsearch

The following request from a python client to elasticsearch fails

```
    2014-12-19 13:39:05,429 WARNING GET http://10.129.0.53:9200/delivery-logs-index.prod-20141218/_search?timeout=20m [status:N/A request:10.010s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 46, in perform_request
    response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=False, headers=headers, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 559, in urlopen
    _pool=self, _stacktrace=stacktrace)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 223, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 516, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 336, in _make_request
    self, url, "Read timed out. (read timeout=%s)" % read_timeout)
ReadTimeoutError: HTTPConnectionPool(host=u'10.129.0.53', port=9200): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)


Elasticsearch([es_host],
                             sniff_on_start=True,
                             max_retries=100,
                             retry_on_timeout=True,
                             sniff_on_connection_fail=True,
                             sniff_timeout=1000)
```

Is there a way to increase the request timeout? Currently it seems to be configured by default to read timeout=10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding a `request_timeout` to a value in your request like:

```
res = client.search(index=blabla, search_type="count", timeout="20m", request_timeout="10000", body={
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also pass `timeout=60` when instantiating the client object (60 meaning 60 seconds and of course being only an example).

This parameter overrides the 10s default specified in the `Connection` constructor.

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/master/elasticsearch/connection/base.py#L27